# Creating a session-scoped proxy for a bean

Tags: java, spring

What might be the problem with this configuration which results in the exception?

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create scoped proxy for bean 'scopedTarget.testProxy': Target type could not be determined at the time of proxy creation.`

```
<bean id="test" class="com.testsession.Test" scope="prototype" />

<bean id="testProxy" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean" scope="session">
    <property name="target" ref="test" />
    <property name="proxyInterfaces"><value>com.testsession.TestIface</value></property>
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

The `testProxy` bean is requested by the session-scoped mvc controller. Is not that the target type specified in the `proxyInterfaces` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up your concepts here - you *either* use `aop:scoped-proxy` *or* you provide an explicit `ProxyFactoryBean` with the appropriate settings, not both.

To use `aop:scoped-proxy`:

```
<bean id="testProxy" class="com.testsession.Test" scope="session">
  <aop:scoped-proxy />
</bean>
```

To configure the proxy bean explicitly:

```
<bean id="test" class="com.testsession.Test" scope="session" />

<bean id="testProxy" class="org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedProxyFactoryBean">
  <property name="targetBeanName" value="test" />
</bean>
```

Note that the proxy is configured with the target bean *name*, not a reference to the actual target bean.

Comment: Thanks. The reason I used ProxyFactoryBean is that I need to alter the Test bean (which is JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean actually), using interceptors maybe (to put username/password in BindingProvider). Would you tell me how I do that using the sample you provided?

Comment: @Industrious I've added a sample of how to configure the proxy explicitly without using `aop:scoped-proxy`